# Is it possible to only generate script tags using html-webpack-plugin and not boilerplate?

Tags: webpack

How can I configure Webpack HTML Plugin to only generate script tags, and not `<html>`, `<body>`, or `<head>` tags?

Answer (score 5):

You can configure `html-webpack-plugin` to build the file based on a custom template. If the template does not have a `<body>` tag, the script includes are simply appended to the end of the file. There are more advanced configuration options available as described in the [project documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates), but for your purpose all you need is to **create an empty file** named e.g. `includes.html`, and then specify it as the template in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'includes.html'
    })
  ]
  ...
}
```

If a completely empty file does not work, just add a newline or a html comment.

Comment: It generates head tag for the scripts

Answer (score 2):

An empty template alone will still result in `<head></head>` tags being generated. As far as I can tell, the [doc page](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) says nothing about removing it, so postprocessing may be required.*

First, you actually don't even need to create a file if you pass an empty string to `templateContent`.

Second, to postprocess, you can use the `beforeEmit` hook. (See flowchart [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#events).) Just define a new plugin. This plugin is based on the one from the GitHub page, but you don't actually need a separate plugin file.

So the **webpack.config.js** looks something like this:

```js
// Define plugin
class ScriptExtractor {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('ScriptExtractor', (compilation) => {
            HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation).beforeEmit.tapAsync(
                'Remove head',
                (data, cb) => {
                    // Remove the unwanted strings
                    data.html = data.html.replace(/^<head>|<\/head>$/g, '');
                    cb(null, data);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        // Use plugin
        new ScriptExtractor,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            // Use empty template
            templateContent: ''
        })
    ]
};
```

---

* There is a nice, short workaround/hack if you're just generating `<script>` tags and nothing else. As s6mike discovered, you can use the empty `templateContent` and `inject: 'body'` (the other values for `inject` do not work):

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: 'body',
            templateContent: ''
        })
    ]
};
```

However, if you are using `base:` to alter the base URL, HtmlWebpackPlugin will once again generate `<head>` tags. I think this is because `<base>` can only go in the `<head>`, and you're now specifying that you want the scripts in the `<body>`. The same may go for the `meta:` property.

Output with `<base>`: `<head><base href="..."></head><script...>`

Comment: I didn't use the ScriptExtractor. When I used an empty template the output was script tags nested inside a head tag (as you stated). When I used an empty templateContent the output was just the script tags.

Comment: Sorry I should have reviewed my config - I'm also using inject: 'body', when I take it out, head tags appear. So try that.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass html webpack plugin a custom template

Comment: If i pass an empty template it still adds html, head, body tags